# Flutter: Could not update Access is Denied

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

So, I was working fine with Flutter even published 2 apps on Playstore but out of a sudden, I can't run any new flutter project.

The error I get is access is denied. Tho older projects are working fine.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
Could not update C:\Users\Dell\.gradle\caches\4.10.2\file-changes\last-build.bin
> C:\Users\Dell\.gradle\caches\4.10.2\file-changes\last-build.bin (Access is denied)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with
--scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
  Command: C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\errr\android\gradlew.bat app:properties


Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
```

Comment: Did you make any administrative permission related change on your computer?

Comment: I didn't recall anything like this. Though I can't see my Users\Dell for is C storage. Flutter is in Users\Dell\flutter folder and i have to search it in C to get it. It didn't come automatically

Comment: Try running flutter build clean

Comment: Then try running your Flutter app again.

Comment: Nope, same error :(

Answer (score 0):

I changed the gradle version to 7.0.2 and it worked for me

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-all.zip
```